# How to do javascript request (supertest, superagent) behaving like curl --data-binary

Tags: javascript, curl, request, supertest, superagent

tl;dr;
Sending below curl works but I cannot do the same in supertest (what wrap superagent https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/)

```
curl 'http://local/api/items' -X DELETE -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' --data-binary '"1234"'
```

---

I can do delete item from web interface where I attach file with required text.
Then using dev tools I extracted curl command presented above and this works as a charm.
How to execute it in js?
Tried:

```
const response = yield request('http://local')
      .delete('/api/items')     
      .set('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')    
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
      .send("1234");
```

Then I get
`"status":400,"error":"BodyNotReadable",`
Maybe using `write` can be an answer but I don't know how to do that.
Full list of available options https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/node/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
request
  .delete('http://url/')
  .set('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
  .send(JSON.stringify(body))
  .type('json')
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
  });
```

The key is to `JSON.stringify` the payload you want to send. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please :

```
request('http://local')
  .delete('/api/items')
  .set('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
  .write("1234")
  .end((err, res) => {
    // Get response here
  });
```

Comment: got ` TypeError: request(...).delete(...).set(...).set(...).write(...).end is not a function`

Comment: What's your version of superagent  please?

Comment: v: SuperAgent 3.5

Comment: can you test request.del('http://local/api/items', '1234', (err, res) => {
  // get response here
}).set('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');